# How to compute a column that is shifted from an existing column in a dataframe and truncate the first and last rows of each group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df = 

integer_id begin 
0          13
0          15
0          18
0          19
1          10
1          15
1          17
```

I want to compute a 3rd column `end` where `df.end` is defined by the next `df.start` for the given `integer_id`, so e.g.,

the above would become

```
df = 

integer_id begin  end
0          13     15
0          15     18
0          18     19
0          19     
1          10     15
1          15     17
1          17
```

Furthermore, for the last row of each `integer_id`, I want `end` to go to `25` and for the first row of each `integer_id`, I want `start` to be truncated to `10`, so ultimately, we would have

```
df = 

integer_id begin  end
0          10     15
0          15     18
0          18     19
0          19     20
1          10     15
1          15     17
1          17     20
```

I am not very good with pandas, but I think I will have to use the `apply` and `groupby('integer_id')` here, or is there another approach I can apply here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html)+[`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and boolean indexing with [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df['end'] = (df.groupby('integer_id')['begin'].shift(-1)
               .fillna(20, downcast='infer')
             )

df.loc[~df['integer_id'].duplicated(), 'begin'] = 10
```

Output:

```
   integer_id  begin  end
0           0     10   15
1           0     15   18
2           0     18   19
3           0     19   20
4           1     10   15
5           1     15   17
6           1     17   20
```